# Get all substrings that start with x and end in y

Tags: javascript

Similar questions have been asked before, but always just a bit different than my requirement.

I basically want to return an array with all user ids that are present in a certain string, except for a reserved id (`<#&IAMSPECIAL>`) that should not be extracted. User ids always following the same pattern:

- they start with <#&
- they end in >

Example:

**Input: string:**

`"<#&ABC123> and <#&JFE832145> should be extracted from this string, just like these two:<#&BCD142><#&ABC123>. This one however should not become part of the array:<#&IAMSPECIAL>"`

**Desired output:**

array: `['ABC123','JFE832145','BCD142','ABC123']`

Notice that there can be duplicates in the array.

I was trying stuff like `string.split('<#&').pop().split('>')[0];` but I fail to get them all out...

Comment: Excluding the reserved ID is easier done by filtering after you find all the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match the pattern `<#&...>`, and then filter out the reserved name from the result.

```js
const string = "<#&ABC123> and <#&JFE832145> should be extracted from this string, just like these two:<#&BCD142><#&ABC123>. This one however should not become part of the array:<#&IAMSPECIAL>";

const result = (string.match(/(?<=<#&).*?(?=>)/g) || []).filter(name => name != "IAMSPECIAL");
console.log(result);
```

`(?<=<#&)` is a lookbehind that matches `<#&` before the match, and `(?=>)` is a lookahead that matches `>` after the match.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! The `.filter` is throwing an error though when no ids are present, which can be the case.